# How to Instrument a React Web App Client using aws xray

Tags: aws-xray

I'm trying to instrument my React Web App using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/scorekeep-client.html

I am using axios interceptor,But unable to instrument any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the axois interceptor code you'll need for X-Ray. Axios does not use the base HTTP library from Node, so you'll need to include this patcher.

I recently wrote a sample app to be published, here is the snippet I used.
Hopefully this helps.

```
const xray = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
const segmentUtils = xray.SegmentUtils;

let captureAxios = function(axios) {

  //add a request interceptor on POST

  axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    var parent = xray.getSegment();
    var subsegment = parent.addNewSubsegment(config.baseURL + config.url.substr(1));
    subsegment.namespace = 'remote';

    let root = parent.segment ? parent.segment : parent;
    let header = 'Root=' + root.trace_id + ';Parent=' + subsegment.id + ';Sampled=' + (!root.notTraced ? '1' : '0');
    config.headers.get={ 'x-amzn-trace-id': header };
    config.headers.post={ 'x-amzn-trace-id': header };

    xray.setSegment(subsegment);

    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    var subsegment = xray.getSegment().addNewSubsegment("Intercept request error");
    subsegment.close(error);

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  // Add a response interceptor
  axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    var subsegment = xray.getSegment();
    const res = { statusCode: response.status, headers: response.headers };

    subsegment.addRemoteRequestData(response.request, res, true);
    subsegment.close();
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    var subsegment = xray.getSegment();
    subsegment.close(error);

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
};

module.exports = captureAxios;
```

Usage

```
Just pass in an initialized instance of Axios.
```

For React, you'll have to tell me a bit more about what your setup is, and what you're trying to accomplish. X-Ray only cares about the routes in your application - typically interceptors are setup on the routes to collect data and create (and close) the root segment ([see the X-Ray SDK for Node Express here](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/blob/master/packages/express/lib/express_mw.js)). For browser-based integration, we're still discussing possible options from the X-Ray end.

Comment: Hi @AWSSandra thanks for the information, I'm looking for a browser-based integration followed the [link](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-java-scorekeep/blob/xray-cognito/public/app/xray.js)

Comment: multiple getSetment() seem wrong, if there can be parallel calls. I changed the code to attach the subsegment to the axios config. Also res can just be response.request.res